# Infinite state automata

Tags: state, infinite, automata

I was asked to prove that for an arbitrary language L, L⊆ {a,b}∗, there exists an infinite state automata M that L = L(M). I have proved that the isa could accept arbitrary string w ⊆ {a,b}∗. I am confused about how to define an arbitrary language or how to define the final state in isa. Here's what I have done.

[image]

Comment: You'll probably have more luck with this question on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I have probably solved the problem. We could construct an M' which could accept every string in {a,b}*. Then to prove that reading each string would lead to a unique state. To prove L=L(M), just make the final state appropriate.